# Finding the highest value of an attribute using ALL in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am supposed to write a query to find "Find name(s) of the artist(s) with the highest total sales".
The query that I wrote is this one:

```
SELECT Ar.Name, SUM(IL.UnitPrice) AS ts
FROM Artist Ar
    JOIN Album Al ON Ar.ArtistId=Al.ArtistId
    JOIN Track Tr ON Al.AlbumId=Tr.AlbumId
    JOIN InvoiceLine IL ON IL.TrackId=Tr.TrackId
    JOIN Invoice I ON I.InvoiceId=IL.InvoiceId
GROUP BY Ar.Name
HAVING ts >= ALL (SELECT SUM(IL.UnitPrice) AS ts
FROM Artist Ar
    JOIN Album Al ON Ar.ArtistId=Al.ArtistId
    JOIN Track Tr ON Al.AlbumId=Tr.AlbumId
    JOIN InvoiceLine IL ON IL.TrackId=Tr.TrackId
    JOIN Invoice I ON I.InvoiceId=IL.InvoiceId
GROUP BY Ar.Name)
```

I am using DB Browser for SQLite and when I run the query it says `near "ALL" syntax error:`
This query should work on Chinook Database, the schema is in [this link](https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chinook_Schema&referringTitle=Documentation)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order by` and `limit`. This would work when there are no ties for the highest sales.

```
SELECT Ar.Name, SUM(IL.UnitPrice) AS ts
FROM Artist Ar
    JOIN Album Al ON Ar.ArtistId=Al.ArtistId
    JOIN Track Tr ON Al.AlbumId=Tr.AlbumId
    JOIN InvoiceLine IL ON IL.TrackId=Tr.TrackId
    JOIN Invoice I ON I.InvoiceId=IL.InvoiceId
GROUP BY Ar.Name
ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1
```

Edit: To get all the maximum sales in case of ties.

```
select t1.name from
(SELECT Ar.Name, SUM(IL.UnitPrice) AS ts
FROM Artist Ar
    JOIN Album Al ON Ar.ArtistId=Al.ArtistId
    JOIN Track Tr ON Al.AlbumId=Tr.AlbumId
    JOIN InvoiceLine IL ON IL.TrackId=Tr.TrackId
    JOIN Invoice I ON I.InvoiceId=IL.InvoiceId
    GROUP BY Ar.Name) t1
JOIN (select max(ts) as maxsale from
          (SELECT Ar.Name, SUM(IL.UnitPrice) AS ts
           FROM Artist Ar
           JOIN Album Al ON Ar.ArtistId=Al.ArtistId
           JOIN Track Tr ON Al.AlbumId=Tr.AlbumId
           JOIN InvoiceLine IL ON IL.TrackId=Tr.TrackId
           JOIN Invoice I ON I.InvoiceId=IL.InvoiceId
           GROUP BY Ar.Name) t) totals 
ON totals.maxsale = t1.ts
```

Comment: What if more than one artist have the same total amount of sales? then we'll only get one of them, right? @vkp

Comment: yes..you would get one of them. see the edited version which would work in case of ties as well.